# How to handle error globally in react apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I have to handle authentication error in react js on each request. So how can I handle authentication error globally?

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink
} from "apollo-boost";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

let apolloClient = null;

if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = fetch;
}

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost/suitecrm/process.php"
});

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  let token = "";
  if (
    localStorage.getItem("token") != null &&
    localStorage.getItem("token") != ""
  ) {
    token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  }

  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      authorization: token ? `${token}` : ""
    }
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

export default function initApollo(initialState) {
  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink), // Chain it with the HttpLink
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
  }
  return apolloClient;
```

I am using the above file for call graphQL queries and mutation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `onError`  of [apollo-link-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-error) package to get errors globally. Apollo-Boost also includes this export.

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, path }) =>
      console.error(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Operation: ${operation.operationName}, Path: ${path}`),
    );
  if (networkError) console.error(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

...

apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to return an error from backend side.

Comment: You need to throw an AuthenticationError. Check the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/errors/) , there is an example with AuthenticationError.

Comment: I have to handle error from PHP then how to return error message from PHP to apollo client.